# How do I force my charts onto one page in SQL Server Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a report with 5 charts on it in **SQL Server Report Builder 2016**. In the "Design" window, the 5 charts appear to be on the same page. In the "Print Layout" window, the charts are now on three different pages. I would like all the charts to be on the same page when printed.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Place them all in a rectangle. This helps keep them together when the report runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your design surface isn't expanded too far to the right.  Make the ruler visible in combination with looking at the margins to make sure the graphs don't spill over to the next page because they are too far to the right.  This is a common problem and I wish the designer had some way to indicate this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have been checking that my graphs are within the margins using the ruler, but the same problem persists... Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually, it looks like that fixed it. I agree that the developers could have done a better job designing that.